# Substraction of predicted values: taking in to account prediction intervals

Tags: predictive-models, negative-binomial-distribution, prediction-interval

I'm trying to make a prediction of the number of annual flu hospitalizations.
In order to do so I'm trying to subtract the predicted number of hospitalizations when there is no flu from the predicted number of hospitalizations when flu is present.

I'm using a negative binomial regression model that includes the number of registered hospitalizations, positive samples for flu and positive samples for 2 other respiratory pathogens.

NBR<- glm.nb(Count ~ INF + RSV + MYP , data = df)
pred<-add_pi(df, NBR, names = c("lpb", "upb"))
pred_NO_flu<-(df0, NBR, names = c("lpb", "upb")) # with df0 = all positive flu samples set to 0

Due to data limitations my prediction intervals are very wide.
How can I account for this when making the subtraction of both predictions?
How can I get a CI for the result of this subtraction?

I'm working in R so examples in R would be very helpful.

Thank you,

Melissa